# Deploy ReactJS Application in AWS Cloud Front

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-redux, amazon-cloudfront

I have some questions regarding deploy a React Application on cloud front.

How the caching and updating of front end website hosted on Cloud Front works?

```
When I upload a new files to the bucket I will see the changes IMEDIATELY after accessing the site again? If not, how long it will take?
I need to make an invalidate request to see the changes working on the website? If yes, how long it will take?
```

What is the best approach to deal with cache and update of Single Page applications in Cloud Front? (I am using a React Application and Webpack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is purge the cache of the bucket or "invalidating" a file.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

So install the aws cli and run the following command:

`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $CDN_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"`

I'd suggest you use your S3 bucket for development.

Comment: Thank You Sergio! I read about invalidation and is exactly that I was thinking. But my question is: how long that will take for the changes have effect when refreshing/reentering in website?

Comment: When you invalidate the cloudfront cache, typically it takes somewhere around 5 mins. Could be less as well. Depends on the resources that you are trying to invalidate.